# mysql strange behaviour with triggers

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table `discussions`, which stores the data of posts on my website.

Now I have 2 triggers,one of which inserts the `path` column when a new row is added, and another one which updates the `path` when a row is updated, as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER discussions_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON discussions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE next_id INT;
SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='discussions');
IF(NEW.visibility<1)
THEN
SET NEW.path = CONCAT('discussions.php?id=',next_id);
ELSEIF(NEW.visibility>=1)
THEN
SET NEW.path = CONCAT('private.php?id=',next_id);
END IF;

CREATE TRIGGER discussions_update_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON discussions FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE next_id INT;
SET next_id = OLD.id;
IF(NEW.visibility<1)
THEN
SET NEW.path = CONCAT('discussions.php?id=',next_id);
ELSEIF(NEW.visibility>=1)
THEN
SET NEW.path = CONCAT('private.php?id=',next_id);
END IF;
```

While this works like it should, every once in a while, when I try to insert or update the table `discussions`, I get the following error :

User 'abhishek'@'`An unknown IP`' is not defined.

However, the user `abhishek` is allowed only from `localhost`.

After trying everything, I discovered that dropping the triggers, and then re-creating them solves the problem. When I got the error again, I re-created the triggers and it worked. What's the problem here?

Comment: How are you creating the trigger? Is it through `mysqli`? Also, can you list the details of the trigger on the DB? Use `how triggers\G` and check for the `definer` value? Is it `user@localhost`?

Comment: @visakh I create triggers using the default mysql client. It seems I can't use `how triggers\G` in mysql client. It gives error.

Comment: Sorry, it was a type from my end...the command is `show triggers\G`

Comment: I see that the definer is not set to `user@localhost` , instead it is `user@some ip`

Comment: I guess you may want to look at your hosts file settings.

Comment: @visakh can i set the definer in mysql configuration file?

Comment: `CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' TRIGGER trigger_name` should work.

Comment: Let me know if the connection issue is recurring. If not, I'll get all these comments together and post as an answer

Comment: @visakh yes it's not recurring now. You can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `show triggers\G` and check whether the `DEFINER` is set to `user@localhost`.

If not, then modify the `DEFINER` of the `TRIGGER` to `user@localhost`. The syntax is as follows:

`CREATE DEFINER='username'@'localhost' TRIGGER trigger_name trigger definition`

For a detailed discussion, see the comments to the question.